# .net wrapper for SMART on FHIR

Tags: .net, hl7-fhir

I am new to SMART on FHIR technology and wanted to create some .net wrapper with SMART on FHIR. anyone please provide suggestions how to start on this and helpful references.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the API are described at http://docs.smarthealthit.org/authorization/, which provides a description of how the authorization process works, with examples. You'll probably want to build on the official .NET API library. You can try using the `BeforeRequest` [property of the Requester](https://github.com/ewoutkramer/fhir-net-api/blob/0573e36a0ccccb3b95b958ddc2dd493acd1dce13/src/Hl7.Fhir.Core/Rest/Requester.cs#L56) to inject an access token as an Authorization header, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be different depending on which UI platform you are targeting.
Winforms, WPF and UWP (or others) will have different controls to assist, so will need different code for each.
Which platform are you looking for specifically?